# Moving menu items into overflow div as menu is resized?

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I've seen some similar questions but the answer seem to revolve around a binary switch between mobile menu and regular menu where some JS is used to hide the regular menu (and show the mobile menu) as soon as any menu item goes into overflow.

What I'm looking to do is remove individual LI elements from the regular menu and move them into an overflow menu as needed,

I'll try to illustrate;

**Initial menu state;**

```
Home | About | Products | Services | Stuff | Contact
```

**Intermidiate state (the window has been resized and "contact" has moved into the overflow area, "..." is the overflow menu which will contain all hidden items.**

```
Home | About | Products | Services | Stuff | ...
```

**The window has been shrunk even more and now only the first 2 menu items can fit, the rest are all in the overflow area now**

```
Home | About | ...
```

Basically, I just want some way to detect when a specific LI has gone into the overflow area so I can act on it accordingly. I'm already using jQuery so I'm fine with any jquery solutions.

Comment: typically once a certain break point hits the whole menu is replaced with a button and a dropdown, most sites do not add navigation links one at a time to a list until they're all gone

Comment: Agreed. I just wanted to handle it in a more dynamic fashion. Kind of like how Windows handles toolbar items (adding them to the dropdown menu 1 by 1 rather than a hard switchover).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spent way too much time on this :-)
It can be done but it's proving quite tricky.

One way is to loop through your menu on window resize and see if the li top position is greater than zero. If so, move it to the next menu.

My demo only moves them from the 1st to 2nd menu. You'll need to figure out a way to move them back.

Here is the code. Sorry I couldn't get a fully working version but a brother needs to get back to work!
http://jsfiddle.net/rxs6q12d/3/

PS. StackOverflow requires a code snippet when linking to jsfiddle. It's not relevant to this post so I'll just...

```
// include some code!
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. I don't fully understand it but I can use it. Specifically, I don't get why top is > 0 when it starts getting cut off.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. This whole time I was working under the idea that I'd need to do overflow hidden to get this to work. I didn't even notice that you were just letting it overflow. Obviously with normal overflow top increases when the LI re-flows to the next line. I actually like it better now because if the person has JS disabled the menu will just re-flow as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Added on to Joe's answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/ha77c42h/1/

Pretty much we reset the original setup, then recompute the second menu. This won't scale well, but it good enough for a small number of elements.

Specifically added:

```
var allArray   = new Array();
$('#menu1 li').each((index, elem) => {
    allArray.push($(elem));
})
$('#menu2 li').each((index, elem) => {
    allArray.push($(elem));
})
$(allArray).each((index, elem) => {
    $(elem).appendTo('#menu1');
})
$('#menu1 li').each(function(index, elem){
    var myposition = $(elem).position();
...
```